# Copy value from one row to all rows having the same groupID

Tags: mysql

Here's my MySQL table:

```
ID  | groupID   | value
------------------------------
1   | 1         | 
2   | 1         | 0.34353
3   | 1         | 
4   | 2         | 
5   | 2         | 0.23232
6   | 3         | 
7   | 3         | 
8   | 3         | 1.23234
9   | 3         |
```

I want to copy the available `values` from each group to ALL rows with the same groupID, so that my final table will look like this:

```
ID  | groupID   | value
------------------------------
1   | 1         | 0.34353
2   | 1         | 0.34353
3   | 1         | 0.34353
4   | 2         | 0.23232
5   | 2         | 0.23232
6   | 3         | 1.23234
7   | 3         | 1.23234
8   | 3         | 1.23234
9   | 3         | 1.23234
```

There is no fixed amount of how many rows one group has. How can I do this?

Comment: Eh... Something like this. `UPDATE \`table\` SET \`value\` = (SELECT \`value\` FROM \`table\` WHERE \`value\` != '') WHERE \`groupID\``... Eeks, got confused in the middle. But something like that.

Comment: do you want to select like that or need to update ?

Comment: @Rams Looks like OP wants to UPDATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using an update join.  Join your initial table to a subquery which identifies the non `NULL` value for each `groupID`.  After bringing in that information, update non `NULL` value columns to the value from the subquery.

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT groupID, MAX(value) AS value
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY groupID
) t2
    ON t1.groupID = t2.groupID
SET t1.value = t2.value
WHERE COALESCE(t1.value, '') = ''
```

**Update:**

It appears that you may have empty string for the missing data, and/or `NULL` in addition to that.  In this case, `MAX()` should still pickup on the non missing data, but I changed the `WHERE` clause appropriately.

Comment: Should we use JOIN? Is there any other way without using JOINs?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Doing a self join in an update is allowed in MySQL, and this is the approach I would use.  You could also update using a correlated subquery, but that might be slower than this, and harder to read.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've tried it (and a bunch of similar queries from other questions), but for some reason it's not working :/

Comment: @rayne Can you quantify what `it's not working` means?  Do you get an error, or is the final table not what you expect?

Comment: I just tried replacing `IS NULL` with `= "";` and it works! Weird. Previously there were 0 rows affected, but with `= "";` it seems to have updated all rows.